# What is the difference between a uint8 and a single image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-scaling, unsigned-integer, single-precision

I already know `uint8` contains intensity values between 0 and 255 (2<sup>8</sup>-1) and single contains values between 0 and 1, it is used to hold larger values without upsetting the range error. But, apart from that, are there any other differences?

What is the difference between `imagesc((I/64)*64)` and `imagesc((Is/64)*64)`, where `I` is `uint8` and `Is` is `single`?

Comment: "_single contains values between 0 and 1_" - that's inaccurate. A `single`-precision variable _may contain_ fractions, but can also contain integers. You should read about the [floating-point representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) of numbers.

Answer (score 3):

`imagesc` just calls `image` underneath. As for `image`, it behaves a bit differently if integers or floats are supplied, as can be learned from [`image`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html#buqdlnb-C)'s documentation:

> If `C` is of type **double**, then an RGB triplet value of `[0 0 0]` corresponds to black and `[1 1 1]` corresponds to white.
>
> If `C` is an **integer** type, then the image uses the full range of data to determine the color. For example, if `C` is of type `uint8`, then `[0 0 0]` corresponds to black and `[255 255 255]` corresponds to white. If `CData` is of type `int8`, then `[-128 -128 -128]` corresponds to black and `[127 127 127]` corresponds to white.
>
> ...
>
> **Converting Between Data Types**
>
> To convert indexed image data from an integer type to type `double`, add 1. For example, if `X8` is indexed image data of type `uint8`, convert it to type `double` using:
>
> ```
> X64 = double(X8) + 1;
> ```
>
> To convert indexed image data from type `double` to an integer type, subtract 1 and use `round` to ensure that all the values are integers. For example, if `X64` is indexed image data of type `double`, convert it to `uint8` using:
>
> ```
> X8 = uint8(round(X64 - 1));
> ```
>
> To convert true color image data from an integer type to type `double`, rescale the data. For example, if `RGB8` is true color image data of type `uint8`, convert it to double using:
>
> ```
> RGB64 = double(RGB8)/255;
> ```
>
> To convert true color image data from type `double` to an integer type, rescale the data and use `round` to ensure that all the values are integers. For example, if `RGB64` is image data of type `double`, convert it to `uint8` using:
>
> ```
> RGB8 = uint8(round(RGB64*255));
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
I = uint8(255*rand(1e3));
Is = single(I)/255;

tmpI = (I/64)*64;
tmpIs = (Is/64)*64;

% plot for prosterity
% figure;
% subplot(211)
% imagesc(tmpI)
% subplot(212)
% imagesc(tmpIs)

numel(unique(tmpI(:))) % gives 5
numel(unique(tmpIs(:))) % gives 256
```

Dividing an integer basically means binning of values, and then it stretches the data back to the original extend for plotting. In this case, you get `256/64 = 4` bins, with 0 as well, thus 5 possible values for your `uint8` image. However, using `single` you retain all unique numbers, since the precision is a lot higher.

If you'd do the same test with a lot (order 2^52) elements in the `rand` and use `double` you'd see that that again has 2^32 times the number of unique elements of `single`, just as `uint16` will have 2^8 the number of unique elements of `uint8`.